# Get more fields instead of only one in Elasticsearch aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I'm new to Elasticsearch and i have a problem with my program.
In order to group the result like "group by" statement in SQL. I used aggregation.
But i realized that there was a problem i need to solve here. I used the following statement to group my result:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "field2"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field3"
              }
            }
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is: the values of field2 and field3 depend on field1 value, so if you could get field1 value, you could also get the values of field2 and field3. Therefore, making aggregation like above would cost so much time to finish my program (I've tested it and realize it costed me 6 times slower than grouping the field1 only).

So my question is: Is it possible to group only the field1 (use only one "aggs"), but get also the field2 and field3 value?
If no, so are there any other possible methods to do my work?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation, you can include any number of fields with [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html), Try this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "include_fields": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100,
            "_source": {
              "include": [
                "field2",
                "field3"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, making "size" equal to 1 is what i need.

Comment: glad I could help, you can make size according to what you want, default is 10